# Choosing site for question about deleting contacts of Gmail account?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm having trouble deleting contacts on my [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) account.

Which Stack Exchange site would this question be best suited for?

Comment: To look for suitable Stack Exchange sites I recommend googling: http://www.google.com/search?q=gmail+stack+exchange

Comment: @PolyGeo this is a slippery road. Very slippery, ending right here in MSE: https://www.google.com/#q=android+bug+stack+exchange. I won't recommend this, and suspect it's the source of 90% of the off topic questions we get here, if not more. (I suspect attaching "bug" to any keyword and adding Stack Exchange will lead people right here.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I probably should have clarified that I was describing a method to look for candidate stack exchange sites - that then need to be verified/eliminated as suitable by reviewing the on-topic pages of those candidates.

Answer (score 5):

The [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) seems like the right place. To quote its Help Center's [on topic page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question generally covers ...
>
> - Using **Gmail**, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
>     
>   [rest of the topics snipped, emphasis added by me]

Answer (score 2):

Questions regarding the use of gmail would be on topic on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

That site has a [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) [tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) and a [google-contacts](/questions/tagged/google-contacts) [tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts) (as noted by [Al E.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/21960/al-e)). So it's possible your question has already been asked and answered there.

Alternatively there's a non-stack place to ask: [A Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail) which covers gmail

Comment: The [google-contacts](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts) tag would be more appropriate. This assumes, of course, that the asker is having trouble using the web interface. If, for instance, they're having trouble with the "People" app on Android, [android.se] would be a more appropriate place to ask.